# How to restrict the instance_types allowed to launch in an AWS Account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

The goal is to restrict future EC2 instances to only types with `nitro` as the hypervisor (i.e. `run_instances`, `modify_instance_attributes`). Ideally at the Service Control Policy (SCP) level in AWS Organizations.

I have written a script to gather a list of all nitro instance types and presently that is 225 instance types or 31 generations (e.g. i3en, m5n, c5d, etc). That's not exactly elegant.

What I have imagined in my head is something like:

```
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
        "ec2:InstanceType/Hypervisor": "nitro"
    }
}
```

But the only thing I know to work looks akin to the following (with all 2

```
"Condition": {
   "StringEquals": {
      "ec2:InstanceType": ["t2.micro", "t2.small"]
   }
}
```

Regardless whether there is a good solution, thanks for taking the time to read this. Cheers.

Comment: You can check the [available IAM condition keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-policy-keys) for EC2. I can't see anything that would allow to specify hypervisor or nitro, or anything similar.

Comment: That has been my impression as well, thank you Marcin. It looks like the only tools available to solve this problem are reactive.

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest solution for an SCP is to use a Deny rule with `StringNotLike`, which can use wildcards:

```
"Effect": "Deny",
"Action": [
    "ec2:RunInstances"
],
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
],
"Condition": {
    "StringNotLike": {
        "ec2:InstanceType": [
            "t2.*",
            "t3.*"
        ]
    }
}
```

This is still, perhaps, more typing that you'd like, but in my experience you want to limit instance types more than just those that use a particular hypervisor. For example, to restrict instances by their hourly cost. This ends up being a relatively small set of strings.

Comment: This is not a valid SCP

Comment: @RobertSzot - it wass copied from an SCP that's been in active use for over two years. What is wrong with it? Or are you simply upset that it doesn't contain the boilerplate fields?

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
         "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "t2.*",
                        "t3.*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @RobertSzot - As far as I can tell, you've just added the boilerplate. I was going to edit, but then noticed that I was very clear in my answer that it was a "Deny rule", not a complete SCP.